# 90V DC motor controller debug

Tags: power-supply

treadmill control board connected to 90V DC motor.
Stopped working.
I can run the motor off a 20V battery and it works fine.
When I connect voltmeter to the control board output the voltage just rises. Starts at 30V and just goes up and up and up finally stops around 110V DC.  the speed control of motor (assume it should lower/raise the voltage) does absolutely nothing.

If I connect the motor the voltage drops very rapidly an the control board relay shuts off.

Any help appreciated.
Steve

[image: control board picture]

Comment: If it is a simple control board, then why haven’t you fixed it? I’d suggest you check obvious things like soldering, burnt or otherwise damaged components. Measure resistors. Without a model reference and a picture, we have no idea of what you are looking at.

Comment: `voltage drops very rapidly an the board relay shuts off` ... overcurrent protection perhaps

Comment: You say it is a 90vdc controller but... - what is the current rating of the motor at 90v?  What is the current rating of your control board?

Comment: A picture might be helpful.  When you mentioned SCR are you referring to "Silicon Control Rectifier" or something else. What is the controller input voltage. What is the application.  How did it failed.  How old is the device.  Is it leadfree or not. We need more info.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. It's a treadmill motor controller <2 years old. 110V AC input. DC output. Picture above in main post. I wish I had schematics but I dont. I've checked all the caps (they are fine),solder joints, resistors, rectifier (seems ok), dont know how to check IGBT. Was hoping that runaway voltage (30V rising to 106V) slowly and drops immdeiately when I plug motor in is indicative of a common failure????? Thanks again – 
Srej
 24